# Is there a way to override the old karate-reports folder with the new karate-report folder instead of creating new reports folder for each execution

Tags: report, karate

Each time I run a feature file as a cucumber feature or using TestRunner class, a new karate-reports_x is being generated inside the target folder. This is leading to more memory consumption. So I'm forced to manually delete the karate-reports folder before i run my feature file the next time. Is there any way we can have only one karate-reports folder which will be overridden for every execution so that i need not delete each time. I'm attaching the screenshot of the karate-reports_x folders that are generated.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: besides the linked answer, why don't you just do `mvn clean` and that will solve all your problems

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas, .backupReportDir(false) worked